# jquery post php send form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to send variables from 2 form elements to another PHP script, through jquery.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, just can't get the variables sent to the other PHP script.
Tried with jquery serialize as well, didn't get that to work either. 
Tried with serialize() command as well.
Any suggestions more than welcome.

Thanks!

```js
When putting the data in url manually, the return is correct. Then in data I have +page, as:
      $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "agent_talktime_pag.load.php?txtDate=2007-03-04&zone=Hongkong",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)

If I use " var datastring  = $('#idForm').serialize(); " the return doesn't work.
The variables get passed in the url, but the issue seems that the page="+page isn't passed. Which makes the load script not work. I tried to add a hidden field in the form like:
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="+page">
But, seems it's not passed as expected by the load script. The +page becomes just a string, think in the $.ajax it functions as a counter?

Any ideas?


 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#driver").click(function(){
    var datastring  = $('#testform').serialize(); 
      
                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='../images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }             
  

     
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                   
      $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "agent_talktime_pag.load.php?txtDate=2007-03-04&zone=Hongkong",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#driver").click(function(){
      var txtDate=$("#txtDate").val();
      var zone=$("#zone").val();
    var dataString = 'txtDate='+ txtDate + '&zone='zone;
    });
      
                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='../images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }             
  

     
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                   
      $.ajax ({
         type: "GET",
                        url: "agent_talktime_pag.load.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
  
  
  
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);
                    
                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <!-- This is a pagination script using Jquery, Ajax and PHP
     The enhancements done in this script pagination with first,last, previous, next buttons -->

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Pagination with Jquery, Ajax, PHP</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery/jquery-ui.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
    </head>
    <body>

    <div align="center" style="font-size:24px;color:#cc0000;font-weight:bold">Pagination with jquery, Ajax and PHP</div>

    <form id="testform">
    <input type="text" name="txtDate" id="txtDate">
    <select id="zone" name="zone">
        <option value="Hongkong">Hongkong</option>
        <option value="EST">EST</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="driver" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

        <div id="loading"></div>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="data"></div>
            <div class="pagination"></div>
        </div>
  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>` are duplicate files. The difference is that min stance for minimized version. So the file is a lot smaller. So you can remove the other one

Comment: Did you try to debug in firebug? What does `dataString` hold on submit? Have you considered to use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)?

Answer (score 0):

To send data you have to do as follows:

Error code:

> var datastring = 'txtDate =' + txtDate + '& zone =' zone;

Code:
    //Manual code

```
 var datastring  = {"name field" txtDate, "fieldname": zone} // zone = field values
```

otherwise:

```
 var datastring  = $('#idForm').serialize();
```

Code ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    data:  datastring, //date form 
    url:   'url',
    type:  'get', //type
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function () {
      //code load
    },
    success:  function (response) 
    {
      //code                       
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at the code! When putting in data in string manually, it works. Seems like the fields are not put in the "post" by $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be posting data in the url as params. You should use data to map out your data fields that you're going to be sending:

```
type: "method",
data: {field1: field1, field2: field2}
```

Comment: When hard coding the url like: _italic_ **bold**                  url:"agent_talktime_pag.load.php",
data: "txtDate=2007-03-04&zone=Hongkong&page="+page, Then the response is working, if I do it using serialize, it doesn't work: type: "GET",
url: "agent_talktime_pag.load.php",
data: $('#testform').serialize() + "&page="+page,